# Email log4j errors to different groups

Tags: java, logging, properties, log4j

Am using log4j for my error reporting. Ive set my log 4j to also append errors to emails. However i need it to send emails to separate groups depending on the level of the message. For example

```
      info messages go to management- john@management.com, peter@management.com, simon@management.com                   
       debug messages go to programmers - paul@programmer.com, matt@programmer.com
       warn messages go to administrator - admin@admin.com
```

In such a fashion,  is it possible? And has anyone implemented said procedure (a sample properties file would be appreciated)

Answer (score 1):

Is should be easy to configure something like this using the [`SMTPAppender`](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/net/SMTPAppender.html) from log4j. But be aware, that emailing logs takes quite a bit of load, especially if you consider mailing `DEBUG` reports to developers.

Comment: do you have a properties file to that effect

Comment: odedpeer uses an xml format which doesnt necessarily translate to a similar result when using a properties file

Comment: Using a filter is only allowed using the DOMConfigurator. Is there any particular reason to use a properties file?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a log4j Filter to do this (http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/spi/Filter.html)

The example below writes messages to different files according to the log level.
This can be easily adapted to an SMTPAppender instead of a FileAppender.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j='http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/'>

    <appender name="management" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="management.log" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%m"/>
        </layout>
        <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter">
            <param name="LevelMin" value="INFO" />
            <param name="LevelMax" value="INFO" />
            <param name="AcceptOnMatch" value="true" />
        </filter>
    </appender>

    <appender name="programmers" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="programmers.log" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%m"/>
        </layout>
        <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter">
            <param name="LevelMin" value="DEBUG" />
            <param name="LevelMax" value="DEBUG" />
            <param name="AcceptOnMatch" value="true" />
        </filter>
    </appender>

    <appender name="admin" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="admin.log" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%m"/>
        </layout>
        <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter">
            <param name="LevelMin" value="WARN" />
            <param name="LevelMax" value="WARN" />
            <param name="AcceptOnMatch" value="true" />
        </filter>
    </appender>

    <category name="a">
        <level value="ALL" />
        <appender-ref ref="management"/> 
        <appender-ref ref="programmers"/>
        <appender-ref ref="admin"/> 
    </category>

</log4j:configuration>
```